# retornando array em php e inserir no html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um script em PHP que está retornando da seguinte maneira

```
{
  "Resultado": [
    {
      "NOMECURSO": "Administração Diurno Sede Ribeirão Preto"
    },
    {
      "NOMECURSO": "Administração Noturno Sede Ribeirão Preto"
    },
    {
      "NOMECURSO": "Agronomia Diurno Campus Ribeirão Preto"
    },
    {
      "NOMECURSO": "Arquitetura e Urbanismo Diurno Campus Ribeirão Preto"
    }
  ]
}
```

Agora em meu arquivo JS estou recuperando o valor da data e tentando colocar o resultado dentro de um select em meu html. mais nao funciona

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'xxxx.php',
    data: {cpf: $('.cpf').val()},
    datatype: "json",
    returnType:"json",
    beforeSend: function() { $('.passo4').hide();$('.loading').show(); },
    complete: function() {  $('.loading').hide();$('.passo4').show();},
    success: function(data){

       var resultado = data;

var $select = $('#data_prova');
 $select.find('option').remove();
$.each(resultado,function(key, value)
{
    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
});     
     }
  });
```

Mais nao recupera! da esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso colocar esses resultados dentro de um select.. alguém pode me ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um erro básico no seu AJAX: o correto é `dataType` ('T' maiúsculo) e não `datatype`. Esse erro faz com que o retorno não seja um JSON parseado, mas apenas uma string JSON.

Outro problema é que o retorno retorna uma array dentro de um objeto `Resultado`, mas como você atribuiu o `data` à uma variável `resultado`, você deveria usar `resultado.Resultado` no `$.each`, e pegar o nome das chaves do objeto usando `value.NOMECURSO`:

```
$select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value.NOMECURSO + '</option>');
```

O código seria:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'xxxx.php',
 data: {cpf: $('.cpf').val()},
 dataType: "json",
 returnType:"json",
 beforeSend: function() { $('.passo4').hide();$('.loading').show(); },
 complete: function() {  $('.loading').hide();$('.passo4').show();},
 success: function(data){

    var resultado = data;

      var $select = $('#data_prova');
       $select.find('option').remove();

      $.each(resultado.Resultado,function(key, value)
      {
          $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value.NOMECURSO + '</option>');
      });     
  }
});
```

Uma dica é que em vez de usar `$select.find('option').remove();`, você poderia usar simplesmente `$select.empty();` que já esvazia o select todo.

> Outra coisa é: onde você achou esse `returnType`? Nem na [documentação
>   oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery possui essa opção.

Comment: Muito Obrigado , ficou perfeito!!!!  sobre o returnType eu vi em outro tópico e acabei colocando para testar... valeu!!!